# white-space: normal not being picked up in IE5 Quirks Mode?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I need to support customers who run IE9 in Quirks mode (which is also known as IE5 quirks mode in IE10). We have simple HTML, which you use to wrap long text in a div:

```
<div id="noteContainer" style="white-space: normal !important;">
    (long string value here)
</div>
```

For all other browsers, the long text wraps correctly. I am ONLY seeing the issue in IE9 Quirks mode (which I must support). I am wondering if this is an IE5 bug (it appears to be so) and if there are any work-arounds for this issue. Thank you very much.

Things I have tried (without luck):

- < p> tag
- white-space: pre-line;
- white-space: pre-wrap;
- word-wrap: break-word;
- word-break: break-all;

Comment: Text should warp by default. Are you sure this isn't another issue, like the div being too wide or hidden behind another element?

Comment: It's not a problem with width. The text attempts to overflow and is cut-off (overflow:hidden;), if I set overflow to 'scroll', a scroll bar appears.

Comment: I figured something out! It's the '!important' that it's not picking up.

Comment: Show a real example, with HTML and CSS that actually reproduce the issue, and state clearly *what* the issue is. (Presumably some text that should wrap does not wrap, but which text where?)